# Install of Windows 7 starter fails

Tags: windows, boot, netbook, eee-pc, boot-manager

So my friend gave me an ASUS Eee PC 1001PXD with a BOOTMGR error to fix. I said that I'll just re-install windows, and it will be fine. But, I've tried to install it for a few times now, and it fails every time. It gives the following error:

> The computer restarted unexpectedly or encountered an unexpected
>   error. Windows installation cannot proceed. To install Windows, click
>   "OK" to restart the computer, and then restart the installation.

The netbook has a BIOS password (?), which no-one know, but when I just press enter, it will go trough it.

Comment: Have you tried jumping it?

Comment: There's probably a way to reset the BIOS password. Check the manufacturer's website, computer users manual if you have one, or searching online.

Comment: I know, by taking the battery off, and pressing the power button for 25s, it should reset the password, but it hasn't done anything.

Comment: @soandos Jumping?

Comment: There is usually a jumper gate that can be used to reset the BIOS password

Comment: @soandos Where actually? On the motherboard?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/456925/remove-bios-password-on-netbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A year later, I finally got to know what was wrong with it.

The HDD was breaking apart, but I managed to install Ubuntu on it, and it worked for a couple months. However, I got it back a few weeks ago for reinstalling, and then I noticed that it didn't boot, because S.M.A.R.T was almost yelling at me to change the HDD.