# How to recover password-locked BIOS?

Tags: bios, passwords, password-recovery

I have a notebook for school and, as I am constantly concerned with security, it is pretty locked. I set up a strong password for every operating system, but I also have set up a password lock on the BIOS, as this notebook's is fairly powerful and configurable. The problem is, I know what was probably my password and some alternatives, but I can't get to unlock it and just have user access.

I need to change some settings, but it is impossible. What I suspected was I somehow had the <kbd>fn</kbd> key pressed while creating the password, but it didn't prove right, and so is the BIOS locked for about one year or more.

ASUS support for this is extremely slow and useless, they had not provided me an answer in 3 months of contact (and they take about 15 days to answer) and asked the model and serial number every single time, so I lost patience. Updating the version also doesn't remove the password.

Notebook is a K43BY and the BIOS is the most up-to-date from the website.

What else can I do?

Comment: When you enter an invalid password, does it give you a 5 or 6- digit number? If so I can likely post a helpful answer.

Comment: No, it just shows "Invalid password" up to 3 tries, then I have to reboot

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/456925/remove-bios-password-on-netbook - Specifically open up the laptop and look for a CLRTC jumper or pad to short.

Comment: If it doesn't give you a hash for the password on the third try and if there is no jumper present, resetting it may involve physically shorting the CMOS to reset or soldering connections. In that case, you may want to contact the manufacturer, regardless of how difficult they are.

Comment: I cannot open it, it's kind of glued or something...

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid your only option is to either remember your password, or clear the CMOS.  Clearing the CMOS generally involves opening the notebook and shorting pins, moving a jumper or just popping out the CMOS battery for a few minutes.

You may void the warranty if you open the laptop so make sure it's worth it before you go messing around.

Comment: Warranty is already expired. Please read my comments to the question and try and help me

Comment: There are no magical answers for people that don't like the answers that are right. You either need to take it to someone who is actually competent to open the case, or become one. If you really think you might know the password, try it with the caps lock on, and try it with the num lock on - otherwise, this answer is spot-on, and your comment is petulant, at best.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same problem in an asus X456UJ. It does not have CMOS battery as a laptop or desktop has normal. It only has a Winbond 25Q64FVSIG 1548 integrated circuit, it is assumed that bypassing legs 7 and 8 the bios are reset, but this did not work.
look for something else with this type of motherboard models with integrated ram and on one side you have the pins to bridge and reset the bios this worked for me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VPSc.jpg)